# How to inject javascript code dynamically before body tag using php?

Tags: php, javascript

Ｉam using a custom mvc framework that i built myself. I would like to ask how can we dynamically include javascript files to the bottom of my page?

Create Account Page (createaccount.php)

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<div class="container maincontainer">
<h3>Create an Account </h3>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

My  tag is in the footer.php.

I have another page called

Login Page (login.php)

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<div class="container maincontainer">
<h3>Login </h3>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Basically, this 2 pages use different javascript files. I want to include different js for different page. Note：they are using same footer.php file

Is there any function/method that i can write to inject js code dynamically to the footer.php based on specific pages? Advice from experts appreciated greatly!

Cheers

Comment: include `js` files after the `footer.php`.

Comment: it will be after the </body> tag (in the footer.php) if i do so.. if there any way to put in just before the </body> tag?

Comment: Create two footer files. In first one write the code before `</body>` tag. In second footer file write code `</body></html>`. Include them in `php` files and in between these files include appropriate `js` files.

Comment: What about include the .js file with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually handle that kind of situation by creating an array on each page of scripts to get injected into the footer:

createaccount.php

```
<?php
$scripts = array('foo.js', 'bar.js');

include('header.php'); ?>

<!-- page specific content -->

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
$scripts = array('http://example.com/baz.js');

include('header.php'); ?>

<!-- page specific content -->

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

footer.php

```
<!-- whatever your footer content is -->

<?php
// script injection
foreach ($scripts as $url) { ?>
  <script src="<?=$url?>"></script>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

That'll allow you to include as many or few scripts on each page as necessary.

Usually I have a php file that'll get included first thing on all pages to handle database connection, sessions, etc. and include the initialization of `$scripts = array()` there; then every page will have `$scripts` initialized to an empty array by default, so that it only needs to get set on the pages themselves if they need to use it.

Comment: This solution is really elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following in your footer.php

```
    <?php 
      $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      $file_info = pathinfo($path);
      $file_name = $file_info['file_name'];

      if($file_name == 'createaccount.php'){
         echo "<script src = 'your_script.js'></script>";
      }else if($file_name == 'login.php'){
         echo "<script src = 'another_script.js'></script>";
      }

    ?>
```

You can also use a switch in case there are a lot of dynamic scripts

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, i am looking for a more scalable way.. i will have alot of php files.. don't really want to have lots of if else statement in the footer.. seems hard to maintain as well~

Comment: @Slay, as I've suggested, you can keep an hash of page_id and js code associated with it. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make a `$script` var in your page that stores the script...then in your footer do `if($script) echo $script;`

Answer (score 0):

If your script is only used for that page, there's no reason why you can't just add the `<script>` tag just before including the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// your code here
</script>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Any elements you need to reference inside the script would have already been added to the DOM by the time your script gets evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, using different js files for different pages wont be a wise choice.

As browser caches the js files once downloaded.

However, you can use inline js for particular pages.

Keep an hash (an array in php) of page_id and js code to be included

In your `footer.php`, just before the `</body>` tag, inline print the js code linked with that page_id.

e.g.

```
$scripts = array('page1' => 'page1 js code', 'page2' => 'page2 js code');
```

and in `footer.php` just before `</body>`,

```
`echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
 echo $scripts['page1'];
 echo '</script>';
```

You wont need any `if/else` in this case.